# Oracle Reports 10g (rwserver.sh) - connecting from a remote server

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

I have an Oracle Reports server 10g (10.1.0.4.2) that for the last few years has been running okay with the rwclient.sh client application residing on the same host.

Due to some performance issues caused by long running/heavy reports we are looking at trying to separate the reports server from the application server.

From memory rwserver.sh  should be able to accept connections from a client on the same LAN, but not on the rwservers localhost (but I'm going back many years since I saw that sort of setup and I was just a developer, not an admin, so I could be misremembering it).

When I try and submit a report across the network I get:

```
dgs@local:~ $ rwclient.sh server=rep_cig userid=test/test@CIGDB report=/home/dgs/report_file/RCL16.rdf desformat=XML destype=FILE desname=/home/dgs/report_output/claims_outstanding.xml imp_comp_id=1619 

REP-0178: Cannot connect to Reports Server 'rep_cig'.
```

I've enabled tracing on the reports server and can see requests on the server coming from the external clients (i think), but I only get one line per report run attempt. (But consistently get this same line so I think the rwclient is at least seeing the rwserver):

```
 [2017/8/4 1:43:19:104] Debug 50103 (ServerPacketReceiver:handlePacket): Got a request packet
```

Looking at the output of  `netstat -tupln`, there seems to be number of ports opened by the reports/java process - most of them open to 0.0.0.0, but a couple are bound to 127.0.0.1:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp6       0      0 :::33886                :::*                    LISTEN      30759/java
tcp6       0      0 :::38083                :::*                    LISTEN      6823/java
tcp6       0      0 :::51140                :::*                    LISTEN      30729/java
tcp6       0      0 :::43429                :::*                    LISTEN      7337/java
tcp6       0      0 :::42182                :::*                    LISTEN      7490/java
tcp6       0      0 :::47181                :::*                    LISTEN      30818/java
tcp6       0      0 :::52270                :::*                    LISTEN      30797/java
tcp6       0      0 :::38711                :::*                    LISTEN      4916/java
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:54063         0.0.0.0:*                           4916/java
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40289         0.0.0.0:*                           7337/java
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           7490/java
udp6       0      0 :::14021                :::*                                30700/rwserver
```

(The java processes above are all for `oracle.reports.engine.RWEngine`)

I assume the 0.0.0.0/127.0.0.0.1 multiple ports things is why the server can see the initial probe, but the client then fails to connect properly.

I suspect there's got to be an option somewhere that determines what interface the server tries to bind to but I can't find any option in the report server .conf to enable this.

Questions:

1. Is it actually even possible to connect to the reports server
   from external clients? and if so;
2. Where abouts do I need to
   configure the reports server so it listens for external connections?